# IBM Rhapsody - alternative IDE?

Tags: windows, software-development, ide

The Rhapsody IDE is very poor compared to MSVC, which itself is nowhere near as good as Qt Creator IDE.

Are there any options to use a different IDE for Rhapsody? Or can you integrate Rhapsody (via plugins?) to other IDEs?

#### Requirements

The IDE should have:

- Good code completion functionality
- Refactoring options
- Integration with SVN/Git
- Good/in depth sym-links for code navigation
- MUST: integrate somehow with Rhapsody

For Windows. Support for Linux would be nice to have, too, but to be honest I doubt that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Rhapsody can run as [plug-in inside Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB2MU_7.5.3/com.ibm.rhapsody.integrating.doc/topics/rhp_r_int_integrating_rhp_and_eclipse.html).

Eclipse alone obviously implements the listed requirements in the question.

The plug-in gives you a "Modelling" perspective that behaves similar to the stand-alone Rhapsody. SVN integration is a bit tricky, because it needs an additional "unit view" to select what to lock/commit. I did not try GIT.